# No perder informacion de un UserControl en WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

Hola estoy trabajando en wpf en mi aplicacion cuento con un listado de TextBlock donde una vez que el usuario de click sobre ello se va a mostrar un UserControl con la informacion correspondiente, mi problema radica en cuando le doy click a otro TextBlock y vuelvo a darle click al anterior,la informacion escrita con por el usuario desaparece. Si me puediran ayudar a solucionar esto.

O sea como hacer para no perder la informacion que se escribe en un user controls una vez q sale del mismo??

Aqui les dejo mi codigo trasero

```
namespace Mudando
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
       
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
          
        }

        private void Out_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }

        private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           
                DragMove();
        }

        private void Menu_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = Menu.SelectedIndex;
            MoveCursorMenu(index);
            switch (index)
            {
                case 0:
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Clear();
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Add(new ID());
                    break;
                case 1:
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Clear();
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Add(new Fundamentation());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Clear();
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Add(new Estrategy());
                    break;
                case 3:
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Clear();
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Add(new Tabla1());
                    break;
                case 4:
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Clear();
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Add(new Planification());
                    break;
                case 5:
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Clear();
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Add(new Resource());
                    break;
                case 6:
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Clear();
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Add(new Tabla3());
                    break;
                case 7:
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Clear();
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Add(new Tabla4());
                    break;
                case 8:
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Clear();
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Add(new Tabla5());
                    break;
                case 9:
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Clear();
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Add(new Tabla6());
                    break;
                case 10:
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Clear();
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Add(new Tabla7());
                    break;
                case 11:
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Clear();
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Add(new Presupuesto());
                    break;
                case 12:
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Clear();
                    GridPrincipal.Children.Add(new Factibilidad());
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }

        private void MoveCursorMenu(int index)
        {
            TransitioningContentSlide.OnApplyTemplate();
            GridCursor.Margin=new Thickness(0,(100 +(60 * index)), 0, 0);
        }

       
    }
}
```

Comment: No se porque perdes informacion, salvo que estes desargando el control... pero sin ver lo que haces, no hay forma de ayudarte...

Comment: Ya agregue mi codigo....gracias por la sugerencia

Comment: Este evento: Menu_OnSelectionChanged se ejecuta cuando? porque cada vez que se ejecuta agrega un nuevo control a GridPrincipal, y los viejos siguen ahi, acumulandose abajo de ese.. creo que solo tenes un problema de posicionamiento...

Comment: Ese evento se ejecuta cada vez q el usuario da un click sobre uno de mis textblock...que me sugieres??

Comment: Entendes que no desaparece no? solamente estas creando uno nuevo. No se que estas tratando de hacer, pero si queres volver a mostrar uno que ya se mostro, deberias guardar la referencia y si ya existe solo traerlo al frente...

Comment: Si me di cuenta que esta creando siempre uno nuevo y q el viejo sigue ahi...cuando cambie el switch por varios if me di cuenta q m los esta agregando uno encima de otro

Comment: Disculapa que lo moleste pero soy nuevo en c sharp podria ayudarme a guardar las referencias y traerlo al frent

Comment: Cuando abras el UserControl lo que debes hacer es enviarle por parámetro un objeto que contenga el valor que quieres setear y que esté FUERA del UserControl mismo, y una vez lo cierras el objeto seguirá en memoria y sin perderse porque lo tienes fuera del UserControl, no lo creaste dentro...

Answer (score 0):

Esto no es un problema de C#...

Esto es un problema de como estas usando WPF...

Para guardar la referencia al control que tenes que mostrar, podrias usar un [diccionario](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0)

De esa forma, defines a nivel de clase:

```
Dictionary<int, UserControl> Controles= new Dictionary<int, UserControl>();
```

Y modifiquemos tu evento:

```
private void Menu_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UserControl c
    int index = Menu.SelectedIndex;
    if (Controles.ContainsKey(index))
    {
        c = (UserControl) Controles[index];
        c.BringToFront();
        // si lo encontramos, volvemos
        return;
    }
    MoveCursorMenu(index);
    switch (index)
    {
        case 0:
            GridPrincipal.Children.Clear();
            //Agregamos esto para cada caso....
            c = new ID()
            GridPrincipal.Children.Add(c);
            break;
        case 1:
            ....etc....
    }
    //Agregamos el nuevo control al diccionario
    Conroles.Add(index, c);
```